# Maven cannot resolve modules

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I'm trying to build the source for [this project (Kryo)](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo). It has two modules defined in `pom.xml`:

```
<modules>
    <module>pom-main.xml</module>
    <module>pom-shaded.xml</module>
</modules>
```

Both modules are in red, with an error like "Cannot resolve symbol `pom-main.xml`"

I haven't found any other examples of a project where the modules are defined by something other than a subdirectory with another `pom.xml` file in it. Here, the two files are siblings to the parent `pom.xml`.

As a result, it is not importing the dependencies of the child modules, and I cannot build the project. I suspect I haven't imported the project correctly in IntelliJ IDEA, but couldn't figure out a different way to do it. I went to Import project and selected the parent directly of the `pom.xml`, and it created a project with a single module called `kryo-parent`. I have tried checking the boxes for "Import Maven projects automatically" and "Create module groups for multi-module Maven projects", but both of these result in the same single module project `kryo-parent` with the unresolved modules.

I tried going to File->New->Module from existing sources..., but it says "Cannot import anything from C:/....pom-main.xml". I tried importing a new project, selecting `pom-main.xml`, but it gave the same error when I select one of these xml files.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? As far as I understood, you have only one module, because you have only one pair (main and test) of java source directories. (Although they are not using the standard maven convention `src/main/java` and `src/test/java`.)

Comment: @VilleOikarinen The dependencies described in `pom-main.xml` are required to build the project. It refuses to recognize `pom-main.xml`, which is described in the sibling `pom.xml` file. Basically, the module that is loaded should include both `pom.xml` and `pom-main.xml`, but it is ignoring the second so it doesn't load all required dependencies. I think the second "shaded" module is used to compile a version that doesn't cause version clashes if this library is combined with another that uses the same dependencies. I don't need to compile that though.

Comment: That is *very* strange organization.

Comment: I've never seen that either. It smells like that never worked. Unless, at some point in time, the project did have two subfolders by that exact name.

Comment: So is the main pom.xml somehow trying to _include_ those other two xml files? I'm not aware of such a feature, and definitely a `module` element is not meant for including snippets. Modules are something completely different.

Comment: I tried importing `pom.xml` in Eclipse, and it works fine. All dependencies from the sibling `pom-main.xml` loaded.

Comment: @Tenfour04 And does maven accept those files and compile, test, install, etc correctly?

Comment: @VilleOikarinen Yes, it does when run from Windows command prompt. At beginning of build it says `Reactor build Order: Kryo Parent, Kryo, Kryo Shaded`, so it is building both modules, apparently. Can't find anything in the documentation about doing it this way, though.

Comment: Let me make a guess: `pom-main.xml` and `pom-shaded.xml` are two different versions of the actual main entry, and they just reuse definitions by inheriting `pom.xml`. So you are not supposed to use `pom.xml` directly but instead you call either `mvn -f pom-main.xml clean install` or ``mvn -f pom-shaded.xml clean install`. Even in that case I don't understand why the parent defines those two alternatives as modules. It doesn't make sense.

Comment: Ah, you explained it while I was typing. Well, like others have said, this is weird use of maven, and clearly IntelliJ IDEA hasn't been design to work with all anomalies maven itself accepts.